# R and Windows Authentication

Tags: r, authentication, kerberos, rcurl

We have a data server set up in IIS using Windows Authentication (Kerberos). Does anyone know how to call web services (GET and POST) from R authenticating against the Windows identity?

Comment: May b you should try https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am trying to just call an http get or post from R, not to call R from .NET...

Comment: `setInternet2(TRUE)` should be of help, asking R to to use windows networking. (if your script execute from a windows box)

Comment: When trying this command in R 3.3.1 I get "Error in setInternet2(TRUE) : use != NA is defunct". Any idea why?

Comment: @Roland Absolutely not, as I'm not using R .3.3.1, maybe reading the doc with `?setInternet2` could be of help ? (And can you confirm you're working on a windows machine ?)

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows. The doc has the answer indeed: "As from R 3.3.0 it changes nothing, and only use = NA is accepted."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Eventually, I found out how to achieve this via NTLM. It is actually simple:

```
require("httr")
GET("http://my-url",authenticate(":", ":", "ntlm"))
```

Comment: nice! your answer made me seem very clever on job today and people were literally celebrating :)